# How to Get User Info in Fingerprint X100-C With Zkemkeeper Using VB.NET

Tags: vb.net, sdk, fingerprint

I have a problem in my project.. i already get Log data in fingerprint device. But when i want to get User Info In fingerprint device to my vb.net application i get error message like this :

> Attempted to read or write protected memory. This is often an
>   indication that other memory is corrupt.

And this is my code for get User Info :

```
Private Sub Button3_Click(ByVal sender As System.Object, ByVal e As System.EventArgs) Handles Button3.Click
    Dim UserID As String
    Dim Passwd As String
    Dim Privilege2 As Integer

    Dim dwEnrollNumber As String

    Dim lvItem As New ListViewItem("Items", 0)

    Dim i As Integer = 0

    With ListView3
        .View = View.Details
        .GridLines = True
        .Columns.Add("No.", 100)
        .Columns.Add("Enroll", 100)
        .Columns.Add("User Name", 100)
        .Columns.Add("Password", 100)
        .Columns.Add("Privilege", 100)
        .Columns.Add("Privilege", 100)
    End With

    ListView3.Items.Clear()
    If zkem.ReadAllUserID(1) Then
        While zkem.SSR_GetUserInfo(1, dwEnrollNumber, UserID, Passwd, Privilege2, Enabled)
            i += 1

            lvItem = ListView3.Items.Add(i.ToString())
            lvItem.SubItems.Add(dwEnrollNumber)
            lvItem.SubItems.Add(UserID)
            lvItem.SubItems.Add(Passwd)
            lvItem.SubItems.Add(Privilege2)
            lvItem.SubItems.Add(Privilege2)

            Application.DoEvents()
        End While
    End If
End Sub
```

What must i do for repair it.

By the way i using Zkemkeeper SDK.

And sorry for my english

Comment: somebody can help me?

Answer (score -1):

```
'**********************************************************
'* Programa para descarga de logs de acceso ZKSoftware
'**********************************************************

Public Class AttLogs

    'Create Standalone SDK class dynamicly.
    Public axCZKEM1 As New zkemkeeper.CZKEM

    '*********************************************************************************************************************************************
    '* Before you refer to this demo,we strongly suggest you read the development manual deeply first.                                           *
    '* This part is for demonstrating the communication with your device.There are 3 communication ways: "TCP/IP","Serial Port" and "USB Client".*
    '* The communication way which you can use duing to the model of the device.                                                                 *
    '* *******************************************************************************************************************************************
#Region "Communication"
    Private bIsConnected = False 'the boolean value identifies whether the device is connected
    Private iMachineNumber As Integer 'the serial number of the device.After connecting the device ,this value will be changed.

    'If your device supports the TCP/IP communications, you can refer to this.
    'when you are using the tcp/ip communication,you can distinguish different devices by their IP address.
    Private Sub btnConnect_Click(ByVal sender As System.Object, ByVal e As System.EventArgs) Handles btnConnect.Click
        If txtIP.Text.Trim() = "" Or txtPort.Text.Trim() = "" Then
            MsgBox("IP and Port cannot be null", MsgBoxStyle.Exclamation, "Error")
            Return
        End If
        Dim idwErrorCode As Integer
        Cursor = Cursors.WaitCursor
        If btnConnect.Text = "Disconnect" Then
            AxCZKEM1.Disconnect()
            bIsConnected = False
            btnConnect.Text = "Connect"
            lblState.Text = "Current State:Disconnected"
            Cursor = Cursors.Default
            Return
        End If

        bIsConnected = AxCZKEM1.Connect_Net(txtIP.Text.Trim(), Convert.ToInt32(txtPort.Text.Trim()))
        If bIsConnected = True Then
            btnConnect.Text = "Disconnect"
            btnConnect.Refresh()
            lblState.Text = "Current State:Connected"
            iMachineNumber = 1 'In fact,when you are using the tcp/ip communication,this parameter will be ignored,that is any integer will all right.Here we use 1.
            AxCZKEM1.RegEvent(iMachineNumber, 65535) 'Here you can register the realtime events that you want to be triggered(the parameters 65535 means registering all)
        Else
            AxCZKEM1.GetLastError(idwErrorCode)
            MsgBox("Unable to connect the device,ErrorCode=" & idwErrorCode, MsgBoxStyle.Exclamation, "Error")
        End If
        Cursor = Cursors.Default


    End Sub
    'If your device supports the SerialPort communications, you can refer to this.
    Private Sub btnRsConnect_Click(ByVal sender As System.Object, ByVal e As System.EventArgs) Handles btnRsConnect.Click
        If cbPort.Text.Trim() = "" Or cbBaudRate.Text.Trim() = "" Or txtMachineSN.Text.Trim() = "" Then
            MsgBox("Port,BaudRate and MachineSN cannot be null", MsgBoxStyle.Exclamation, "Error")
            Return
        End If
        Dim idwErrorCode As Integer

        'accept serialport number from string like "COMi"
        Dim iPort As Integer
        'Dim sPort = cbPort.Text.Trim()
        Dim sPort As String = cbPort.Text.Trim()
        For iPort = 1 To 9
            If sPort.IndexOf(iPort.ToString()) > -1 Then
                Exit For
            End If
        Next

        Cursor = Cursors.WaitCursor
        If btnRsConnect.Text = "Disconnect" Then
            AxCZKEM1.Disconnect()
            bIsConnected = False
            btnRsConnect.Text = "Connect"
            lblState.Text = "Current State:Disconnected"
            Cursor = Cursors.Default
            Return
        End If

        iMachineNumber = Convert.ToInt32(txtMachineSN.Text.Trim()) '//when you are using the serial port communication,you can distinguish different devices by their serial port number.
        bIsConnected = AxCZKEM1.Connect_Com(iPort, iMachineNumber, Convert.ToInt32(cbBaudRate.Text.Trim()))

        If bIsConnected = True Then
            btnRsConnect.Text = "Disconnect"
            btnRsConnect.Refresh()
            lblState.Text = "Current State:Connected"
            AxCZKEM1.RegEvent(iMachineNumber, 65535) 'Here you can register the realtime events that you want to be triggered(the parameters 65535 means registering all)
        Else
            AxCZKEM1.GetLastError(idwErrorCode)
            MsgBox("Unable to connect the device,ErrorCode=" & idwErrorCode, MsgBoxStyle.Exclamation, "Error")
        End If
        Cursor = Cursors.Default
    End Sub
    'If your device supports the USBCLient, you can refer to this.
    'Not all series devices can support this kind of connection.Please make sure your device supports USBClient.
    Private Sub btnUSBConnect_Click(ByVal sender As System.Object, ByVal e As System.EventArgs) Handles btnUSBConnect.Click
        Dim idwErrorCode As Integer

        Cursor = Cursors.WaitCursor
        If btnUSBConnect.Text = "Disconnect" Then
            AxCZKEM1.Disconnect()
            bIsConnected = False
            btnUSBConnect.Text = "Connect"
            lblState.Text = "Current State:Disconnected"
            Cursor = Cursors.Default
            Return
        End If

        If rbUSB.Checked = True Then 'the common USBClient
            iMachineNumber = 1 'In fact,when you are using common USBClient communication,parameter Machinenumber will be ignored,that is any integer will all right.Here we use 1.
            bIsConnected = AxCZKEM1.Connect_USB(iMachineNumber)
        Else
            If rbVUSB.Checked = True Then 'connect the device via the virtual serial port created by USB
                Dim sCom As String = ""
                Dim bSearch As Boolean
                Dim usbcom As New SearchforUSBCom
                bSearch = usbcom.SearchforCom(sCom)

                If bSearch = False Then
                    MsgBox("Can not find the virtual serial port that can be used", MsgBoxStyle.Exclamation, "Error")
                    Cursor = Cursors.Default
                    Return
                End If

                Dim iPort As Integer
                For iPort = 1 To 9
                    If sCom.IndexOf(iPort.ToString()) > -1 Then
                        Exit For
                    End If
                Next

                iMachineNumber = Convert.ToInt32(txtMachineSN2.Text.Trim())
                If iMachineNumber = 0 Or iMachineNumber > 255 Then
                    MsgBox("The Machine Number is invalid!", MsgBoxStyle.Exclamation, "Error")
                    Cursor = Cursors.Default
                    Return
                End If

                Dim iBaudRate = 115200 '115200 is one possible baudrate value(its value cannot be 0)
                bIsConnected = AxCZKEM1.Connect_Com(iPort, iMachineNumber, iBaudRate)
            End If

        End If

        If bIsConnected = True Then
            btnUSBConnect.Text = "Disconnect"
            btnUSBConnect.Refresh()
            lblState.Text = "Current State:Connected"
            AxCZKEM1.RegEvent(iMachineNumber, 65535) 'Here you can register the realtime events that you want
        Else
            AxCZKEM1.GetLastError(idwErrorCode)
            MsgBox("Unable to connect the device,ErrorCode=" & idwErrorCode, MsgBoxStyle.Exclamation, "Error")
        End If
        Cursor = Cursors.Default
    End Sub

    Private Sub rbVUSB_CheckedChanged(ByVal sender As System.Object, ByVal e As System.EventArgs) Handles rbVUSB.CheckedChanged
        If rbVUSB.Checked = True Then
            If bIsConnected = True Then
                MsgBox("Invalid Operation!", MsgBoxStyle.Exclamation, "Error")
                rbVUSB.Checked = False
                Return
            End If
            rbUSB.Checked = False
            txtMachineSN2.Enabled = True
        End If
    End Sub

    Private Sub rbUSB_CheckedChanged(ByVal sender As System.Object, ByVal e As System.EventArgs) Handles rbUSB.CheckedChanged
        If rbUSB.Checked = True Then
            If bIsConnected = True Then
                MsgBox("Invalid Operation!", MsgBoxStyle.Exclamation, "Error")
                rbUSB.Checked = False
                Return
            End If
            rbVUSB.Checked = False
            txtMachineSN2.Enabled = False
        End If
    End Sub
#End Region

    ' **************************************************************************************************
    ' * Before you refer to this demo,we strongly suggest you read the development manual deeply first.*
    ' * This part is for demonstrating operations with(read/get/clear) the attendance records.         *
    ' * ************************************************************************************************
#Region "AttLogs"
    'Download the attendance records from the device.
    Private Sub btnGetGeneralLogData_Click(ByVal sender As System.Object, ByVal e As System.EventArgs) Handles btnGetGeneralLogData.Click
        If bIsConnected = False Then
            MsgBox("Please connect the device first", MsgBoxStyle.Exclamation, "Error")
            Return
        End If

        Dim idwTMachineNumber As Integer
        Dim idwEnrollNumber As Integer
        Dim idwEMachineNumber As Integer
        Dim idwVerifyMode As Integer
        Dim idwInOutMode As Integer
        Dim idwYear As Integer
        Dim idwMonth As Integer
        Dim idwDay As Integer
        Dim idwHour As Integer
        Dim idwMinute As Integer

        Dim idwErrorCode As Integer
        Dim iGLCount = 0
        Dim lvItem As New ListViewItem("Items", 0)

        Cursor = Cursors.WaitCursor
        lvLogs.Items.Clear()
        AxCZKEM1.EnableDevice(iMachineNumber, False) 'disable the device
        If AxCZKEM1.ReadGeneralLogData(iMachineNumber) Then 'read all the attendance records to the memory
            'get records from the memory
            While AxCZKEM1.GetGeneralLogData(iMachineNumber, idwTMachineNumber, idwEnrollNumber, idwEMachineNumber, idwVerifyMode, idwInOutMode, idwYear, idwMonth, idwDay, idwHour, idwMinute)
                iGLCount += 1
                lvItem = lvLogs.Items.Add(iGLCount.ToString())
                lvItem.SubItems.Add(idwEnrollNumber.ToString())
                lvItem.SubItems.Add(idwVerifyMode.ToString())
                lvItem.SubItems.Add(idwInOutMode.ToString())
                lvItem.SubItems.Add(idwYear.ToString() & "-" + idwMonth.ToString() & "-" & idwDay.ToString() & " " & idwHour.ToString() & ":" & idwMinute.ToString())
            End While
        Else
            Cursor = Cursors.Default
            AxCZKEM1.GetLastError(idwErrorCode)
            If idwErrorCode <> 0 Then
                MsgBox("Reading data from terminal failed,ErrorCode: " & idwErrorCode, MsgBoxStyle.Exclamation, "Error")
            Else
                MsgBox("No data from terminal returns!", MsgBoxStyle.Exclamation, "Error")
            End If
        End If

        AxCZKEM1.EnableDevice(iMachineNumber, True) 'enable the device
        Cursor = Cursors.Default
    End Sub
    ' Download the attendance records from the device.
    'The returned time is in strings(different from function GetGeneralLogData)
    Private Sub btnGetGeneralLogDataStr_Click(ByVal sender As System.Object, ByVal e As System.EventArgs) Handles btnGetGeneralLogDataStr.Click
        If bIsConnected = False Then
            MsgBox("Please connect the device first", MsgBoxStyle.Exclamation, "Error")
            Return
        End If
        Dim idwErrorCode As Integer

        Dim idwEnrollNumber As Integer
        Dim idwVerifyMode As Integer
        Dim idwInOutMode As Integer
        Dim sTime = ""

        Dim lvItem As New ListViewItem("Items", 0)
        Dim iGLCount = 0

        Cursor = Cursors.WaitCursor
        lvLogs.Items.Clear()
        AxCZKEM1.EnableDevice(iMachineNumber, False) 'disable the device
        If AxCZKEM1.ReadGeneralLogData(iMachineNumber) Then 'read the records to the memory
            'get the records from memory
            While AxCZKEM1.GetGeneralLogDataStr(iMachineNumber, idwEnrollNumber, idwVerifyMode, idwInOutMode, sTime)
                iGLCount += 1
                lvItem = lvLogs.Items.Add(iGLCount.ToString())
                lvItem.SubItems.Add(idwEnrollNumber.ToString())
                lvItem.SubItems.Add(idwVerifyMode.ToString())
                lvItem.SubItems.Add(idwInOutMode.ToString())
                lvItem.SubItems.Add(sTime)
            End While
        Else
            Cursor = Cursors.Default
            AxCZKEM1.GetLastError(idwErrorCode)
            If idwErrorCode <> 0 Then
                MsgBox("Reading data from terminal failed,ErrorCode: " & idwErrorCode, MsgBoxStyle.Exclamation, "Error")
            Else
                MsgBox("No data from terminal returns!", MsgBoxStyle.Exclamation, "Error")
            End If
        End If

        AxCZKEM1.EnableDevice(iMachineNumber, True) 'enable the device
        Cursor = Cursors.Default
    End Sub
    ' Download the attendance records from the device.
    '"GetGeneralExtLogData" is an enhanced function of the function GetGeneralLogData, but it is compatible with GetGeneralLogData.
    ' Some machines have the WorkCode function; this function can gain the WorkCode when user passes the virification.
    Private Sub btnGetGeneralExtLogData_Click(ByVal sender As System.Object, ByVal e As System.EventArgs) Handles btnGetGeneralExtLogData.Click
        If bIsConnected = False Then
            MsgBox("Please connect the device first", MsgBoxStyle.Exclamation, "Error")
            Return
        End If
        Dim idwErrorCode As Integer

        Dim idwEnrollNumber As Integer
        Dim idwVerifyMode As Integer
        Dim idwInOutMode As Integer
        Dim idwYear As Integer
        Dim idwMonth As Integer
        Dim idwDay As Integer
        Dim idwHour As Integer
        Dim idwMinute As Integer
        Dim idwSecond As Integer
        Dim idwWorkCode As Integer
        Dim idwReserved As Integer

        Dim lvItem As New ListViewItem("Items", 0)
        Dim iGLCount = 0

        Cursor = Cursors.WaitCursor
        lvLogs.Items.Clear()
        AxCZKEM1.EnableDevice(iMachineNumber, False) 'disable the device
        If AxCZKEM1.ReadGeneralLogData(iMachineNumber) Then 'read the records to the memory
            'get the records from memory
            While AxCZKEM1.GetGeneralExtLogData(iMachineNumber, idwEnrollNumber, idwVerifyMode, idwInOutMode, idwYear, idwMonth, idwDay, idwHour, idwMinute, idwSecond, idwWorkCode, idwReserved)
                iGLCount += 1
                lvItem = lvLogs.Items.Add(iGLCount.ToString())
                lvItem.SubItems.Add(idwEnrollNumber.ToString())
                lvItem.SubItems.Add(idwVerifyMode.ToString())
                lvItem.SubItems.Add(idwInOutMode.ToString())
                lvItem.SubItems.Add(idwYear.ToString() & "-" + idwMonth.ToString() & "-" & idwDay.ToString() & " " & idwHour.ToString() & ":" & idwMinute.ToString() & ":" & idwSecond.ToString())
                lvItem.SubItems.Add(idwWorkCode.ToString())
                lvItem.SubItems.Add(idwReserved.ToString())
            End While
        Else
            Cursor = Cursors.Default
            AxCZKEM1.GetLastError(idwErrorCode)
            If idwErrorCode <> 0 Then
                MsgBox("Reading data from terminal failed,ErrorCode: " & idwErrorCode, MsgBoxStyle.Exclamation, "Error")
            Else
                MsgBox("No data from terminal returns!", MsgBoxStyle.Exclamation, "Error")
            End If
        End If

        AxCZKEM1.EnableDevice(iMachineNumber, True) 'enable the device
        Cursor = Cursors.Default
    End Sub
    'Get the count of attendance records in from ternimal.
    Private Sub btnGetDeviceStatus_Click(ByVal sender As System.Object, ByVal e As System.EventArgs) Handles btnGetDeviceStatus.Click
        If bIsConnected = False Then
            MsgBox("Please connect the device first", MsgBoxStyle.Exclamation, "Error")
            Return
        End If
        Dim idwErrorCode As Integer
        Dim iValue = 0

        AxCZKEM1.EnableDevice(iMachineNumber, False) 'disable the device
        If AxCZKEM1.GetDeviceStatus(iMachineNumber, 6, iValue) = True Then 'Here we use the function "GetDeviceStatus" to get the record's count.The parameter "Status" is 6.
            MsgBox("The count of the AttLogs in the device is " + iValue.ToString(), MsgBoxStyle.Information, "Success")
        Else
            AxCZKEM1.GetLastError(idwErrorCode)
            MsgBox("Operation failed,ErrorCode=" & idwErrorCode, MsgBoxStyle.Exclamation, "Error")
        End If

        AxCZKEM1.EnableDevice(iMachineNumber, True) 'enable the device
    End Sub
    'Clear all attendance records from terminal.
    Private Sub btnClearGLog_Click(ByVal sender As System.Object, ByVal e As System.EventArgs) Handles btnClearGLog.Click
        If bIsConnected = False Then
            MsgBox("Please connect the device first", MsgBoxStyle.Exclamation, "Error")
            Return
        End If
        Dim idwErrorCode As Integer

        lvLogs.Items.Clear()
        AxCZKEM1.EnableDevice(iMachineNumber, False) 'disable the device
        If AxCZKEM1.ClearGLog(iMachineNumber) = True Then
            AxCZKEM1.RefreshData(iMachineNumber) 'the data in the device should be refreshed
            MsgBox("All att Logs have been cleared from teiminal!", MsgBoxStyle.Information, "Success")
        Else
            AxCZKEM1.GetLastError(idwErrorCode)
            MsgBox("Operation failed,ErrorCode=" & idwErrorCode, MsgBoxStyle.Exclamation, "Error")
        End If

        AxCZKEM1.EnableDevice(iMachineNumber, True) 'enable the device
    End Sub
#End Region
End Class
```